# How can I map a route to a specific controller action with a specific hard-coded value in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a method with this signature:

```
[Route("g/{name}")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> ForumIndex(string name)
```

This works when I navigate to say, `g/forum` it will call this action with `forum` as the parameter `name`.

However I want to set up a special route that navigating to just `/forum` will call this action with the parameter as "forum".

I've tried the following in my `Program.cs` but it doesn't work:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "forum-route", 
                       pattern: "forum", 
                       defaults: new { area = "Forum", 
                                       controller = "Forum",  
                                       action = "ForumIndex", 
                                       name = "forum" });
```

What am I missing? I am sure this is possible.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 MVC.

Comment: https://chat.openai.com/share/840c57ae-8e8e-4b1d-a26e-562d7d92851f

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding an additional attribute route to my method for `forum` and use a regex constraint so it wouldn't be caught by the previous:

```
[Route("g/{name:regex(^forum$)}")]
[Route("forum/{name=forum}")]
```